# Bigquery execute expression from string column

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In bigquery, ive a table which has an expression which needs to be dynamically substituted and executed.

Eg

Config table
Table, condition
XYZ, "if(1>2,true,false)"

I tried procedural execute immediately.

```
Declare condition string default = (select condition from config_table);
Declare SQL string;
Set SQL ="Select * from other_table Where @condition";

Execute immediate SQL using condition as condition
```

It is replacing the value as string instead of evaluating the expression. Is there any way to substitute it as an expression ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below:

```
Declare condition string default (select condition from config_table);
Declare SQL string;
Set SQL ="Select * from other_table Where %s";

Execute immediate format(SQL, condition)
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. I'm looking at the documentation. If we need multiple substitutions, we can add it multiple format element which is good. Do you know if we can map the format element and the expression like how we do in execute immediate USING ?